# How to print header of GridView on each print page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, vb.net

How do I print the page title and the header of a `GridView` on each print page?

I want to add page title and `GridView` heading on each page.

I used page break to break the `GridView` into multiple pages, but only the first page comes with title and all other are without header and title  page.

For a dynamic `GridView`, my code uses `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`.

Answer (score 4):

Put the below in the head

```
<style media="print">

                .MyCssClass thead
                {
                    display: table-header-group;
                }

</style>
```

Now put your gridview in a div and give the div the class name MyCssClass

Now add the GridView1_RowDataBound event and in that event call the below function passing the Gridview object.

```
private void MakeGridViewPrinterFriendly(GridView gridView)
        {
            if (gridView.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gridView.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                gridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                //gridView.HeaderRow.Style["display"] = "table-header-group";
            }
        }
```

this works with IE and FF. not tested in Chrome.

Comment: +1 for a simple working answer.  I can confirm it works in IE and does not work in Chrome.