# Print two column header in gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have gridview with header with two columns and I want to make to be visible on each page.

Header is created in following function:

```
Protected Sub grdOriginal_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdOriginal.RowCreated

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

        Dim HeaderRow As GridViewRow = New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert)
        Dim Cell_Header As TableCell = New TableCell()
        Cell_Header = New TableCell()
        Cell_Header.Text = "Ознака табле"
        Cell_Header.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        Cell_Header.Width = "150"
        Cell_Header.RowSpan = 2
        Cell_Header.Font.Bold = True
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Header)

        Cell_Header = New TableCell()
        Cell_Header.Text = "Површине делова табли по процембеним разредима"
        Cell_Header.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        Cell_Header.Width = "370"
        Cell_Header.Font.Bold = True
        Cell_Header.ColumnSpan = 8
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Header)

        Cell_Header = New TableCell()
        Cell_Header.Text = "Укупна површина табле"
        Cell_Header.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        Cell_Header.Width = "70"
        Cell_Header.RowSpan = 2
        Cell_Header.Font.Bold = True
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Header)

        Cell_Header = New TableCell()
        Cell_Header.Text = "Укупна вредност табле"
        Cell_Header.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        Cell_Header.Width = "70"
        Cell_Header.RowSpan = 2
        Cell_Header.Font.Bold = True
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Header)

        Cell_Header = New TableCell()
        Cell_Header.Text = "Примедба"
        Cell_Header.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        Cell_Header.Width = "70"
        Cell_Header.RowSpan = 2
        Cell_Header.Font.Bold = True
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(Cell_Header)

        e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False
        e.Row.Cells(9).Visible = False
        e.Row.Cells(10).Visible = False
        e.Row.Cells(11).Visible = False
        'e.Row.Cells(4).Visible = False
        'e.Row.Cells(12).Visible = False
        'e.Row.Cells(13).Visible = False
        'e.Row.Cells(14).Visible = False
        grdOriginal.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderRow)

    End If
End Sub
```

I’m try to use: [How to print header of GridView on each print page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317756/how-to-print-header-of-gridview-on-each-print-page), This working when I have one column for header but don’t working when I try to make two columns header.

Any body have any idea how to do that?

Thanks
I have gridview whith

Answer (score 1):

The [THEAD](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/thead.html) is the element that keeps the header of the table on each printed page.

What you have to do is to set it on the grid view as:

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

where `GridView1` is the id of your GridView. This is [not yet working on google chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826).

reference:
[Having Google Chrome repeat table headers on printed pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211229/having-google-chrome-repeat-table-headers-on-printed-pages)
[Repeat table headers in print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/css-repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode)
[How do I get Gridview to render THEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309101/how-do-i-get-gridview-to-render-thead)